# solvable group and abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, solvable-groups

From wiki, a group $G$ is solvable if there are subgroups $1 = G_0 \trianglelefteq G_1$⋅⋅⋅$\trianglelefteq G_k = G$ such that $G_{j−1}$ is normal in $G_j$, and $G_j /G_{j−1}$ is an abelian group, for $j = 1, 2, …, k$.

I have the problem that we just choose $1\trianglelefteq$G and we get  $G$  is sovable,so any group is solvable,am I wrong?

Comment: Can you use LaTeX? You seem to be proving that Abelian groups are solvable, not the other way around.

Comment: The definition is only saying that there exist subgroups. The definition does not preclude extra subgroups in between. You can squeeze subgroups in between, allowing for $G$ not to be abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your problem: it only says that if a group $G$ is abelian, then it is solvable. Not the other way around: $S_3$ is solvable, but not abelian.

Comment: thanks a lot ,but by definition,every is solvable?

Comment: If you mean abelian groups, then yes, in general, no, there are groups that do not have a normal series with abelian factors. Take for example $A_5$, this group is non-abelian and simple and the only normal series is $1 \lhd A_5$.

Answer (score 1):

In the notation of the definition, for the sequence $1\trianglelefteq G$ we have $G_0 = 1$ and $G_1 = G$, and we require that $G_1/G_0$ is an abelian group. Since $G_1/G_0 = G/1 \cong G$, this sequence only shows that $G$ is solvable if $G$ is abelian.